# webpack dev server callback in start script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I have this dev script in my package.json where it build my app

`"dev": "npm run build && webpack-dev-server"`

but I want to update my yalc, I have this `yalc push --changed --private`, where can I run it after webpack-dev-server done building? I can't add it and the back of the script because it must be run after finished building

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.